# Custom add to cart form

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, custom, addtocart

I would like to create my own custom add to cart form which is the same as original but with custom retrived products. How would I do that in a custom block?

the block class

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Custom\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Variants extends Template
{
    protected $productFactory;

    protected  $_coreRegistry;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry ->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry ->registry('current_product');
    }

    /**
     * Get default qty - either as preconfigured, or as 1.
     * Also restricts it by minimal qty.
     *
     * @param null|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function getProductDefaultQty($product = null)
    {

        $qty = $this->getMinimalQty($product);
        $config = $product->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $configQty = $config->getQty();
        if ($configQty > $qty) {
            $qty = $configQty;
        }

        return $qty;
    }

    /**
     * Get Validation Rules for Quantity field
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getQuantityValidators()
    {
        $validators = [];
        $validators['required-number'] = true;
        return $validators;
    }

    public function getVariants($product)
    {
        if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            $variants = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);

            foreach ($variants as $variant) {
            }
            return $variants;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php
$buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart');
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');

if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    $variants = $block->getVariants($currentProduct);
    $parent = $block->getCurrentProduct();

    if($variants) { ?>
        <div id="product_variants">
        <?php foreach ($variants as $_product) : ?>
              <form class="product_addtocart_variant">
                  <div class="box-tocart">
                      <div class="variant-info">
                          <strong><?php echo  $_product->getName(); ?></strong>
                          <span>Artikelnummer: <?php echo  $_product->getSku(); ?></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="fieldset">
                          <div class="variant-container">
                              <div class="variant-price">
                                  <span>Brutto: <?php echo  $_product->getPrice(); ?> <?php echo  $_product->getCurrency(); ?></span>
                                  <span>Netto: </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="quantity">
                                  <div class="control">
                                      <input type="number"
                                             name="qty"
                                             id="qty"
                                             maxlength="12"
                                             value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty($_product) * 1 ?>"
                                             title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                                             data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="actions">
                                  <button type="submit"
                                          title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                                          class="action primary tocart"
                                          id="product-addtocart-button">
                                      <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <script>
            require([
                'jquery',
                'mage/mage',
                'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
                'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
            ], function ($) {
                'use strict';

                $('.product_addtocart_variant').mage('validation', {
                    radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                            bindSubmit: false
                        });

                        widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php };
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add button in custom phtml file as follow, I have done this in custom module

In your block file

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
<?php
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    }

public function getProductCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
   $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    return $collection;
}
public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
?>
```

get productlist in view file

```
<?php 
const PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL = 'r64';
const PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED = 'uenc';
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
$_productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getName()?>
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                    class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>
    </form>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Hope that helps.